Issues with comparing two model properties using `Compare` attribute ( .net 7)
I am building a sign-up form using .net Blazor server side, while trying to compare the password with the confirmation password field that the user enters are matching, I do the comparison using Compare attribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.
The Same model that used for the form, is also used as Entity for the database, however, I excluded C_ConfirmPassword property mapping to the database.
I get the following response on the form submit
{
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status":400,
    "traceId":"00-67a0409fa8a7445ce4b89e2599b708a9-674a1213be763602-00",
    "errors":{
          "C_ConfirmPassword":["Passwords don't match."]
    }
}

This is my model

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace BPS_Shared.Models;

[Index(nameof(C_Passport_No), nameof(C_Email), nameof(C_Phone), IsUnique = true)]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int C_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name length can't be more than 30.")]
    public string C_Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string C_Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string C_Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Compare(nameof(C_Password), ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match.")]
    public string C_ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string C_Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string C_Passport_No { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Bill.Customer_Id))]
    public List<Bill> Bills { get; set; } = new List<Bill>();
}


`  private async Task OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
{
    NewCustomer.C_Password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.EnhancedHashPassword(NewCustomer.C_Password,13);

    //var Check = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.EnhancedVerify(NewCustomer.C_ConfirmPassword, NewCustomer.C_Password);

    //NewCustomer.C_ConfirmPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.EnhancedHashPassword(NewCustomer.C_ConfirmPassword, 13);



    var responseModel = await CustomerService.CreateAsync(NewCustomer);

    NewCustomer = new Customer();

    success = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}

`
first, I thought the issue might be because the encryption so I commented it out, even the first part of my ( OnValidSubmit) method, I was still getting the same error, I removed the [JSONIGNORE] line from my model and it worked, data was stored to my database. I tried to uncomment the encryption part and try submitting the for again, I again get the same error even though I entered the same password twice.

Hi @Khalid, did you tried to remove [JsonIgnore] attribute from the C_ConfirmPassword property? if not try and post what the error you receive
